c# net 6 api client certification
I have an implementation problem when authenticating with client certificate in my c# api project.
In development the authentication with the client certificate works correctly for me, but when I publish it on IIS 10 the certificate is not sent
I enabled the SSL request and inserted the certificate into the binding

You need to explain more on "I enabled the SSL request and inserted the certificate into the binding". IIS site bindings only work with server certificates, which are completely different from client certificates. You will have to edit the question to include more details, or it is impossible to discuss further.

in the binding settings I added the https protocol on port 443 and selected the certificate I created (self-signed), then I enabled Request SSL and the client certificate request

What do you mean by the certificate not being sent? Is the client unable to receive the certificate from the server or something else? Are you testing on the same machine (server and client)? If possible, please provide more details, such as an error message or relevant log information.
